# Double validation

Tags: java, casting, double

I have the below json property which holds the numeric value

```
 "creditLimit": "844500"
```

which has the following conditions:

1. Should not exceed 10 digits
2. Must be a whole number, should not have decimals

Below are example valid inputs for which I want to throw a validation error message back to the user, saying invalid entry:

```
45500.00
9876543210
```

Example invalid inputs:

```
540.50
98765432109
```

When I tried

```
 Double.valueOf(ent.creditLimit).intValue()
```

the final value alters, looks like it round off the value.

I do not want to keep the decimals.

How to retain the exact value? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't convert to `int` if you want to keep the decimal part. If that's not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: By storing the original `String`. That is the **only** way. There is no difference in binary between `(double) 2`, `2.0` and `2.00`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I do not want to keep the decimals

Comment: What are the exact values in your example and what is your desired output?

Comment: @brso05, updated

Comment: If the value is `540.50` what do you want the output to be?

Comment: If the value is `45500.00` what do you want the output to be?

Comment: If the value is `9876543210` what do you want the output to be?

Comment: @brso05, updated the story, I want to throw a validation error message for those entries

Comment: @user3919727 You could use regular expressions to validate the data...

Comment: @user3919727 please see my answer, it should help you determine if the number is a whole number or not...

Answer (score 2):

You could either use a regular expression to validate or you could parse as a BigDecimal then use `intValueExact()`:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("540.50");
try
{
    bd.intValueExact();
    //number is a whole number
} catch(ArithmeticException e)
{
    //number is not a whole number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure there is a `javax.validation` implementation in your classpath/runtime.
2. In your JSON-Pojo, then:

   ```
   @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{1,10}$")
   private String creditLimit;
   ```

Allows only numerical strings of length 1 to 10. Throws exception otherwise.